# Copying a pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I'm sending some data through the network from the client <> server. I'm reading a packet without any issues, though I can not copy a `SimpleTestPacket` pointer for some reason. I have tried using `memset` where I am getting a segmentation fault.

Code:

```
typedef struct simpleTestPacket_t {
    uint32_t type;
    uint8_t point;
    int32_t value;
} SimpleTestPacket;

void onReceivePacket(uint8_t header, const char* data, size_t count) {
    const SimpleTestPacket* packet = reinterpret_cast<const SimpleTestPacket*> (data);

    SimpleTestPacket* independentPacket = nullptr;
    memset(independentPacket, packet, sizeof(SimpleTestPacket) * count);
}
```

How can I copy the `packet` pointer to the `independentPacket` variable so I could store it for a later-use? Would it be possible to make a copy without allocating a `new` memory which I would have to `delete` later?

Comment: To copy anything you need space. So if you are not interested in the new you can create a variable on the stack.

Comment: @HemantGangwar Oh. That makes sense. Thank you Sir.

Comment: If you want to copy some data, you want memcpy not memset.  Also, you need to reserve space for your packet.  Currently you have a pointer to null, so rather than initialising to null, malloc the number of bytes required.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - `memset`  isn't `memcpy`. Secondly if ` onReceivePacket` would know the packet type, it wouldn't receive a `void*` and if it doesn't, then `count` is going to be in bytes.

Comment: use a copy ctor: SimpleTestPacket independentPacket = packet;

Comment: Btw. the `typedef` thing is redundant in C++ and your pointer/`memset` business makes no sense as mentioned by others. I suggest you read a good C++ book as learning C++ by trial and error tends to end in disaster.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Yes. I have ordered one and currently waiting for the shipment :-).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just drop the unnecessary pointer business, make a local copy and deal with that:

```
const SimpleTestPacket* packet = 
         reinterpret_cast<const SimpleTestPacket*> (data);

auto independentPacket = *packet;
```

Now `independentPacket` is a local copy of `packet` with [automatic storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: Would I be able to store it into the class variable for a later usage without any undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Lucas: Yes, C++ has value semantics. You have to make it hard for yourself to get memory leaks and the like (although unfortunately many schools still teach outdated techniques like `new/delete` which are more risky).

Comment: @Lucas You can use that quite like a normal `int`. So as long as you store it "by value", that is as a plain `SimpleTestPacket` and not through a reference or pointer to `SimpleTestPacket`, everything is fine. Otherwise, the usual life time considerations apply. Again, the rules are the same as for any normal variable, including built-in types such as `int`.

Comment: Thank you guys. Btw. as it's going to be a normal variable and not a pointer I could initialize to `nullptr` - I would probably have to initialize it using `memset` instead of `nullptr` but how could I check, if it's initalized and not empty then?

Comment: @Lucas Normal variables cannot be "empty". They can, indeed, be uninitialized, but you can avoid issues with that by just initializing your variables at the point of declaration, as I did in the code snippet above.

Comment: @Lucas Value types are not "nullable".  There are ways to make values nullable -- anything from sticking a `bool` beside them called `is_valid` to `std::experimental::optional` -- but quite often the answer is "don't make the data until you know it is there".